# React-Native connect multiple devices to one packager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, react-native

When I was on version 0.51 I was able to connect 2 physical devices to one packager. Android and iPhone were both updating after a Hot-Reload, so the workflow was very fast. Now, after upgrading to 0.55 I can only connect 1 device at a time or after Hot-Reloading I well get a crash on the device I connected last. I tried opening a different terminal for each device and starting a packager with another port. But metro always wants to connect to port 8081, the parameter will get ignored. I can only run one terminal anymore. Does somebody have a solution to this case?